# Collection is empty, however, if(!empty($tags)) evaluates to true

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to render some HTML code only if the `$tags` collection is not empty. However, even though the collection is empty the HTML code gets rendered.

When I `dd($tags)`, I get an empty `[]`. Any reason why is this happening?

```
@if(!empty($tags))
    <p><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Tags</p>
    <div class='image-tags'>
        @foreach($tags as $tag)
            <a class='image-tag' href="#">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Try with `sizeof($tags) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
@if(count($tags) > 0)
    More code here ....
@endif
```

as `$tags` is an array

Comment: But if the array has a lot of elements, this will take significantly longer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP sees a Laravel collection just as an object. If that object is not `null`, the `empty` function will always return true. If you want to check if the collection has elements, you can use the [`isNotEmpty`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-isnotempty) collection function.

```
@if($tags->isNotEmpty())

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `count($tags)` for array like or `$tags->count()` if is a laravel collection

Answer (score 0):

Please check on this url, http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php here the proper use of empty function is given.

In your condition if $tags is an array then you should use like this:

```
if(count($tags) > 0)
```